# Trouble accessing object within object

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
var items = {}; //object to store everything
var ilist = [
//a couple items to pull data from
];

ilist.forEach(function(ilist, index){
    var item = {
        quantity: //getQuantity().text(),
        type: //getType().text()
    }
    items["item"+index] = item;
});

console.dir(items);
```

The console output for this shows:

```
Object
    item0: Object
        quantity: "xx"
        type: "xx"
    item1: Object
        quantity: "xx"
        type: "xx"
```

So it looks like objects within an object and everything is already stored properly. Then I try getting things out of it with console.log(items[0]), console.log(items.item0) and I get undefined in the console. console.log(items.item0.quantity) returns: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quantity' of undefined. Why am I not able to pull anything out of the object? I was hoping to turn this into a JSON object, but JSON.stringify(items); didn't work either.

Comment: And what items['item0'] says ?

Comment: actually it says Uncaught ReferenceError: item0 is not defined

Comment: please add the content of `ilist`.

Comment: Weird... can you create a quick snippet where you reproduce please ? it may be related to the "ilist" variable which is used two times...

Comment: @CodingNinjaInTraining Did you try `items['item0']` or `items[item0]`? `items['item0']` _does_ work and is easier written as `items.item0`. `items[item0]` is obviously wrong. I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: Your code works as is (when you plug in hard-coded values for quantity, type, and items).. there must be issues happening elsewhere. https://repl.it/ChXs/1

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use reduce instead of forEach

```js
var list = [
  {id: 0, name: 'item0', qty: 1, type: 'type1'},
  {id: 1, name: 'item1', qty: 2, type: 'type1'},
  {id: 2, name: 'item2', qty: 1, type: 'type1'},
  {id: 3, name: 'item3', qty: 3, type: 'type1'}
];

var items = list.reduce(function(previous, item, index){
  var newItem = {
    quantity: item.qty,
    type: item.type
  };
  
  previous["item" + index] = newItem;
  return previous;
}, {});

console.log(items['item0']);
```

I didnt know how you create your items so I created my own but it's just an example... However, this should work...

Answer (score 0):

You're using forEach slightly wrong...  the parameters of the callback are 
the element value
the element index
the array being traversed

So your forEach is redefining the 'ilist' variable with the current element value.

Try working from

```
ilist.forEach(function(element, index){...} {
var item = {
    quantity: element.quantity
```

...

Doing it like that, I had no trouble with console.log(items.item0);